# Generate count of group memberships x days after group creation

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of group_id, member_id, and created_at.

I'm trying to track the growth in group membership across time.  Since group_id's are created when the first member_id joins, the min(created_at) for a given group should give the created date.  I think this broken code gets the point across for what I'm trying to do (at the month level in this case):

```
   SELECT brand_id,
    min(created_at) as created_date,
    min(created_at) + INTERVAL '1 month' as end_date, 
    count(member_id)
   FROM member_group
   HAVING created_at < end_date 
   group by 1
```

Comment: Whats the point of `HAVING created_at < end_date` ? Also can you explain better your problem with a small set of data and what you want as a result from it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT g.brand_id, x.created_date, x.end_date, count(g.member_id)
FROM member_group g
JOIN (
  SELECT brand_id,
      min(created_at) as created_date,
      min(created_at) + INTERVAL '1' month as end_date
  FROM member_group
  GROUP BY brand_id
) x 
ON ( g.brand_id = x.brand_id
     AND g.created_at BETWEEN x.created_date AND x.end_date )
GROUP BY g.brand_id, x.created_date, x.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    brand_id,
    count(created_at < brand_date + interval '1 month' or null) as total
from
    member_group
    inner join (
        select brand_id, min(created_at) as brand_date
        from member_group
        group by 1
    ) s using (brand_id)
group by 1
order by 1
;
```